# Virtual Functions Object Slicing

Tags: c++, function, virtual, vtable

My question is with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082291/virtual-function-calling-using-dereference-object) which explains how virtual functions work in case of object slicing which end up calling base class virtual function and [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which explains the virtual table layout for a derived class for below code

```
    class A{

    public:
     virtual void func(){ cout<<"\n In A:func";}
    };

    class B:public A{

    public:
     virtual void func(){ cout<<"\n In B:func";}
    };

   main(){
    A *ptr1 = new B();

    A oA = *ptr1;

    oA.func(); 
  }




      DerviedClassObjectB:
         +0: pointer to virtual method table of B 

       virtual method table of B:
         +0: B::func
```

Above program outputs "In A::func" .

But how does without virtual table for class B knowing about base class A::func ends up calling A::func

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Virtual table for class `B`"? Virtual table for class `B` is not involved in `oA.func()` call at all. Object `oA` has type `A`, which means that its virtual table is that of class `A`.

Moreover, most compilers will optimize the `oA.func()` call so that it won't use any virtual tables at all. Since the type of `oA` is known at compile time, the `oA.func()` call can be immediately directed to `A::func` without using any virtual tables.

Answer (score 17):

```
A oA = *ptr1;
```

This copies any member variables into a new A object. The vtable pointer is not a normal member variable and is *not* copied. Thus any subsequent virtual functions called against this object will act as if it is an A object, because it *is* an A object.