# overriding function not worked

Tags: c++, overriding

I have a base and derived class which derived class is overriding a function in base class

```
struct Base{
virtual void action(){}
}

struct Derived:public Base{
virtual void action() override{}
}
```

I have another class that uses Base interface like following

```
struct Observable{
  deque<Base> myObjects;

  void addObject(Base &base){
     myObjects.push_back(base);
  }
  void notify(){
     for (auto it = myObjects.begin(); it != myObjects.end(); it++) {
            it.action();
     }
  }
}
```

In main I initialized observer class like this

```
Derived myDeived;
Observable observable;
observable.addObject(myDerived);
observable.notify();
```

the problem when I call "notify" and as a consequence it call all "action" function in array It does not call "action" function overrided in Derived but in Base class? please explain me why this happened and how to correct it?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does polymorphism work in C++ without pointers / references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670936/does-polymorphism-work-in-c-without-pointers-references)

Comment: `deque<Base>` is a deque of `Base` *object*. For polymorphism and virtual functions to work you need to have *pointers* to the base type (or references).

Comment: @Spinkoo thank you for great answer

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you too