# Can instantiate a virtual object on the heap, but not on the stack?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Let me preface this by saying I'm coming from a Java background, so please forgive me if I've made some stupid mistake here....

I'm writing a C++ library that I would like to make compatible with both Arduino as well as the RaspberryPi. Most of the code is just clean, standard C++, but a few functions are hardware-specific (GPIO calls, for instance). Being from a Java background, I thought, I'll just create a HAL interface that defines those hardware-specific functions, and then I can create implementations of that interface for the RPi and Arduino, only to find out that interfaces are not a thing in C++ and you have to use virtual methods instead. **Please see the bottom of my question for my source files.**

However, when I went to actually use this, I discovered something quite strange: using the HAL on the heap compiles, but using it on the stack does not

```
//THIS DOES NOT COMPILE
MyLibraryHAL hal = HAL_RaspberryPi();
hal.someHwSpecificFunction(65);

//BUT THIS DOES
MyLibraryHAL* hal = new HAL_RaspberryPi();
hal->someHwSpecificFunction(65);
```

The error is:
`src.ino:67: undefined reference to MyLibraryHAL::someHwSpecificFunction(unsigned char)`.

Why is this? Is this just a feature of how virtual methods work? Or is there some concept I'm missing here?

---

`MyLibraryHAL.h`

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef MyLibraryHAL_h
#define MyLibraryHAL_h

class MyLibraryHAL
{
    public:
        virtual void someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param);
};

#endif
```

`HAL_Arduino.h`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "MyLibraryHAL.h"

#ifndef HAL_Arduino_h
#define HAL_Arduino_h

class HAL_Arduino : public MyLibraryHAL
{
    public:
        void someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param);
};

#endif
```

`HAL_Arduino.cpp`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "HAL_Arduino.h"

void HAL_Arduino::someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param)
{
    //do things
}
```

`HAL_RaspberryPi.h`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "MyLibraryHAL.h"

#ifndef HAL_RaspberryPi_h
#define HAL_RapsberryPi_h

class HAL_RaspberryPi : public MyLibraryHAL
{
    public:
        void someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param);
};

#endif
```

`HAL_RaspberryPi.cpp`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "HAL_RaspberryPi.h"

void HAL_RaspberryPi::someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param)
{
    //do things
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193485/discussion-on-question-by-android-dev-can-instantiate-a-virtual-object-on-the-he).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual Functions Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479712/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without pointer, you copy a HAL_RaspberryPi to a MyLibraryHAL instance, then call the method on the superclass (which is not defined).

So yes, use a pointer, but you should use std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointers.

Comment: You mean to say that the superclass need to define that method?

Comment: It has to be defined somewhere, either by the parent class (not PURE) or by the sub-class in the case of PURE func()=0 style methods. If you do not define an implementation and try to instantiate in the heap, you'll get runtime surprises.

Comment: Hope this helps, @Android Dev

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining why my snippet didn't compile instead of just telling me to read a C++ book (which, I freely admit, would be a good thing to do)

Comment: Note, AFAIK, `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` aren't part of the Arduino toolchain, but you can do `Tools\Manage libraries...` and add the `ArduinoSTL` library to your toolchain. Then do: `Sketch\Include library` and find the `ArduinoSTL` almost at the bottom of the list. Then do `#include <memory>` and you now have access to `std::auto_ptr` which is very old, but better than nothing, so you can do `std::auto_ptr<MyLibraryHAL> hal( new HAL_RaspberryPi() );` and have your `HAL_RaspberryPi` instance automatically destructed when the smartpointer goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You /can/ do this by making your stack variable a reference:

```
Base& base = Derived(args);
```

But realistically it doesn't do you a lot of favours, as the reference can only be assigned where it is declared, so the best you can do to avoid construction is:

```
Base& base = Do1 ? Derived1(args) : Derived2(args);
```

You have to be very wary of the lifetime extension rules for references. Make of this what you will:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```cpp
MyLibraryHAL hal = HAL_RaspberryPi();
```

*slices* the `HAL_RaspberryPi` object, so there is only a `MyLibraryHAL` object remaining. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/).

You need a pointer or a reference in order to make polymorphic calls at runtime. That is why your heap example works. See [Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/). You can use polymorphism with objects that are instantiated on the stack, but you still need a pointer/reference in order to make the calls, eg:

```cpp
HAL_RaspberryPi pi;
MyLibraryHAL &hal = pi;
hal.someHwSpecificFunction(65);
```

```cpp
HAL_RaspberryPi pi;
MyLibraryHAL *hal = &pi;
hal->someHwSpecificFunction(65);
```

As for the linker's "undefined reference" error, you did not actually *implement* the  `someHwSpecificFunction()` method in the `MyLibraryHAL` class, you merely *declared* it, thus the error when trying to call it on a `MyLibraryHAL` object. If you don't want to provide a default implementation, you can declare the method as a "pure abstract" method:

```cpp
class MyLibraryHAL {
public:
    virtual void someHwSpecificFunction(uint8_t param) = 0;
};
```

Pure abstract methods must be overriden in descendant classes.  A class that contains only pure abstract methods and nothing else is the closest thing you can get to an "interface" in other languages.