# virtual function hierarchy in c++

Tags: c++, virtual

I got a little bit confused with the topic of virtual functions in c++.
Is there a flowchart that summarize all possible cases?

for example:

```
    class A {
       public:
          virtual void f(const int i) { cout << "A::f" << endl; }
    };

    class B : public A {
       public:
          // Hide A's f with new implementations
          void f() { cout << "B::f" << endl; }
    };

    class C : public B {
       public:
          void f() { cout << "C::f" << endl; }
    };
class D : public B { public:
    void f(const int i) { cout << "D::f" << endl; }
};


    void main() {
       D d;
       C c;
       B* pb = &c;
       pb->f();
       A* pa = &d;
       A* paa = &c;
       pa->f(1);
       paa->f(1); //in here C::f would be invoked?
    }
```

In this case, `B` hides `A::f`, and `C` has an override for `B::f` with the same signature.

Would `pb->f()` invoke `C::f`? 
Would `pa->f(1)` invoke `A::f`?

I ask it to know if `B::f` is still considered virtual so its derivative classes can override it, though it hides `A::f`.

As well as If C::f is considered virtual by default?

Comment: _"Would `pb->f()` invoke `C::f`?"_ [No.](http://ideone.com/qgVKPt) and [yes](http://ideone.com/emlHrt) if you provide the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: you mean once you hide the the base virtual function, the hiding function is not virtual by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual function calling using dereference object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082291/virtual-function-calling-using-dereference-object)

Comment: @Day_Dreamer You might want to read here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/override-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A::f` and `B::f` are two different functions, even though they have the same name; since `B::f` was not declared as `virtual` only `A::f` is virtual - and nobody overrides it.

`pb->f()` uses the static type of the pointer, which is `B*`, to determine which function to call; that would be `B::f`.

Answer (score 2):

> Would `pb->f()` invoke `C::f`?

No, it won't.

> I ask it to know if `B::f` is still considered `virtual` so its derivative classes can override it, though it hides `A::f`.

`B::f()` is not a `virtual` member function.

To make `B::f()` a virtual member function, you have to use:

```
class B : public A {
   public:
      // Hide A's f with new implementations
      virtual void f() { cout << "B::f" << endl; }
};
```

**Update**

You updated your post with the following additional question:

> Would `pa->f(1)` invoke `A::f`?

Yes, it would. Seen through `pa`, neither `B::f()` nor `C::f()` exist, only `A::f(int)` exists.

Comment: If I would have declared B::f with the same signature it would be virtual by default, even without explicit "virtual". so you imply that the default "virtual" is removed when B::f is hiding A::f with different signature?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer, that is partially correct. By default, functions are not virtual. Since `B::f()` is not related to `A::f(int)`, it is not virtual by default. Hence removal of "virtual" is not the right way to think about it. "virtual" is not there to start with.

Comment: @Day_Dreamer: That's right, a function is only implicitly virtual if it overrides a virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a flowchart that summarize all possible cases?

In full generality, you would need to know the entire set of name lookup rules in C++, which is unfortunately very complicated.

Assuming you just want to know what overrides what, you can find all the details in a few paragraphs in the standard.

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly
>   from `Base`, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is
>   so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

...

> Even though destructors are not inherited, a destructor in a derived class overrides a base class destructor
>   declared virtual; see 12.4 and 12.5.

...

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden
>   function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, the
>   return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
>     classes
> - the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D::f`, or is an
>     unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
> - both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f`
>     has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of `B::f`.

Because `B::f` does not have the same parameter types as `A::f`, `B::f` does not override `A::f`, and for the same reason, `C::f` does not override `A::f`. Since `B::f` is not declared `virtual` *and* it does not override `A::f`, `B::f` is not virtual. `C::f` does not override `B::f` because `B::f` is not virtual.

Since `B::f` is not virtual, `pb->f()` always invokes `B::f` and not any function named `f` in a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

`B::f` does **not** override `A::f` because they do not have the same parameter-type-list and therefore it is also not virtual, [class.virtual]/p2:

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, **parameter-type-list** (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

So a derived class method can be implicitly virtual whether or not it has the `virtual` specifier, only if it matches certain properties of the base class method. In this case `B::f` is not virtual and so `pb->f()` uses the static type of the pointer, `B*`, and calls `B::f` and not `C::f`.